# Treeview with parent node on top

Tags: android, treeview

Hi Developers i am looking for a lib that will help me to create this type of treeView in android

https://ibb.co/cwxQKQ

Tanks for Help

Answer (score 0):

I am co-author of the Library TreeView which could solve your problem. The look of the nodes can be adjusted via xml, only the edges you would have to adjust yourself so they look the way you need it.

https://github.com/Team-Blox/TreeView

your node.xml could be something like this:

```
<LinearLayout>

    <ImageView/>
    <TextView/>

</LinearLayout>
```

then you have to create a your tree like this:

```
// example tree
TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode(getNodeText());
rootNode.addChild(new TreeNode(getNodeText()));
...
```

then pass the object to the `BaseTreeAdapter` and voilà you have your Tree.

**Edit:**
The library is in an early stage of development and in the meantime the api has changed! Since I can't customize the post every time, just follow the steps in the description.

Comment: I am trying to use treeview in a project. How to provide different layouts for parent and child nodes (define more than 1 type of node xml). Can you provide some example/tips?

Comment: @JunaidHamza, the example I wrote is obsolete. TreeView is now GraphView and is based on RecyclerView. Use it like a recycler view to use different styles for your edges.